# How to extract y axis labels from boxplot in R?

Tags: r, boxplot, yaxis

How to extract the y-axis labels from the boxplot in R?

Example,

`bxp = boxplot(1:100)`

The y-axis labels are 0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100. I wonder how to extract this programmingly?

Comment: Probably `?axTicks` - run `axTicks(2)` when the plot is still open. I thought this had to be a duplicate, but I'm struggling to find one now.

Comment: @thelatemail THANKS A LOT. I couldn't find any, not just in cross validated, but also in google..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`?axTicks` should do  it, so long as the resulting `boxplot` graphics device window is still open:

```
axTicks(2)
#[1]   0  20  40  60  80 100
```